# image_tagで@user.imageがデータと一致せず表示されない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**前提・実現したいこと**
image_tagでpublicの画像を表示したい。

【理想】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

画像が表示されない。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**該当のソースコード**
【理想図時のコード】

```
<%= image_tag "/uploads/user/image/#{@user.id}/2016-11-18__1_.jpg" %>
```

【画像が表示されない時のコード】

```
<%= image_tag "/uploads/user/image/#{@user.id}/#{@user.image}" %>
```

【データベース】

```
image: "2016-11-18__1_.jpg
```

#### 試したこと

・**#{@user.image}.jpg**などのように拡張子を変えました。

何が間違っているのか全くわかりません…
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/55795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決。

以下を消したら、無事表示されるようになりました。

【user.rb】

```
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```